# Ruby wrapper for Instagram API

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, api, instagram

I've created my first gem as Instagram API wrapper https://github.com/agilie/instagram_api_gem. I would be very pleased if you give me some feedback on code organization, methods elegancy and so on.

The thing I concerned about the most is next. I have a module `Resource`

```
  module Resource
    include Client

    private

    def show(id, options = {})
      raise 'Resource ID is required' unless id
      make_request resource_path(id), query: options
    end

    def index(id, resource_name, options = {})
      raise 'Resource ID is required' unless id
      make_request resource_path("#{id}/#{resource_name}"), query: options
    end

    def create(id, resource_name, options = {})
      raise 'Resource ID is required' unless id
      make_request(resource_path("#{id}/#{resource_name}"), { body: options }, :post)
    end

    def destroy(id, resource_name, resource_id = nil, options = {})
      raise 'Resource ID is required' unless id
      path = "#{id}/#{resource_name}"
      path = "#{path}/#{resource_id}" if resource_id
      make_request(resource_path(path), { query: options }, :delete)
    end
  end
```

And I use methods from it like this

```
  class Tag
    include Search
    include Resource

    def initialize(tag_id = nil)
      @tag_id = tag_id
    end

    def recent_media(options = {})
      index @tag_id, 'media/recent', options
    end
  end
```

Does this implementation look good or are there more elegant solutions?
I would be very pleased if you give me some feedback regarding the whole code organization and implementation, which could be found here https://github.com/agilie/instagram_api_gem

You are welcome to contribute if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I find your code to be very good and readable :)

In the code you present here, I only see one mishaps :

```
raise 'Resource ID is required' unless id
```

is repeated multiple time and actually don't test for much.
I'd consider making a private method that check `id` and also check if id is not `empty` (or even if it isn't `strip.empty?` to consider only-spaces strings).

For the `create` method, can the `option` parameters really can be an empty hash ? If not I'd consider at least removing the default value for this.

I haven't read your whole repo, so I'm not sure but does the `Tag` class really need to include both `Search` and `Ressource` ?

Code like

```
@user_id = user_id ? user_id : 'self'
```

should be replaced with `@user_id = user_id || 'self'`

One important point : your code must be hard to unit test as it is coupled with *HTTParty*, you should consider using a *Strategy pattern* here.

Finally, I'd make some simple class that have only one or two fields (such as `Tag`, `Location`, `User`...) immutable by duping and freezing the parameter and freezing the whole object : (note that it won't work if you expect a boolean, a number, a Symbol or `nil` as `dup` raise an exception in such case :()

```
def initialize(user_id)
  @user_id = (user_id || 'self').dup
  @user_id.freeze
  freeze
end
```

I haven't done Ruby in some time so I'm a bit rusty but I hope my review helped you at least a bit :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I appreciate and will take all your recommendations into account.

Comment: @SergeyMell no problem :)